# Branching Process: Why has conjugate branching process extinction probability $1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a branching process with offspring distribution $(p_k)_{k  \geq 0}$ such that $\sum_k k p_k >1$ (supercritical) and extinction probability $0 <\eta < 1$ (as supercritical).

The conjugate offspring distribution is $(p_k'):=\eta^{k-1} p_k$

Now we want to show that the extinction probabilty $\eta'$ of the branching process with offspring distribution $(p_k')$ is 1.

The hint is that the extinction probability is the smallest solution to $\eta'=G_{X'}(\eta')$, where $G_{X'}(s)$ is the probabiblity generating function of the offspring distribution $(p_k')$.

Moreover, we have tht $G_{X'}(s)=1/{\eta} G_X(\eta s)$, where $G_X(s)$ is the probability generating function of the offspring distribution $(p_k)$.

So we would have $\eta'=G_{X'}(\eta')=\frac{1}{\eta} G_X(\eta \eta')$

But how do we conclude that we have $\eta'=1$?

Comment: The reason is that $\sum kp'_k<1$ hence the conjugate branching process is subcritical. Can you prove this? You will need to use the fact that $\eta$ solves $G_X(\eta)=\eta$ and $\eta<1$ hence $G'_X(\eta)<1$. (A more structural reason is that the conjugate process is the original branching process conditioned on extinction.) (Typo in the OP: $0<\eta<1$, not $\eta>1$.)

Comment: Thanks for your hint and pointing out the typo. So I tried to do the following:
$\sum_k k p_k' = \sum_k k \eta^{k-1} p_k= 1/\eta \sum_k k \eta^k p_k$.

My idea is to use that $\sum_k \eta^k p_k = G_X(\eta)=\eta<1$ but I am not sure how to get rid of the factor $k$.   

Moreover I am a little bit confused since we stated this result as corollary of the fact that $G_{X'}(s) = 1/\eta G_X(\eta s)$.

Comment: By the way, concerning your last comment, the more structural reason: We have seen a duality theorem showing this relation. But I cannot see an intuitive reason why $\eta^{k-1}$ is the right factor to have in order to "condition on extinction". Can you give me some intuitive reason why this is the right thing to do?

Comment: Obviously, $\sum kp_k\eta^{k-1}=\left(\sum p_k\eta^k\right)'=G'_X(\eta)$. Now your task is to show why $\eta=G_X(\eta)$ with $\eta<1$ implies $G'_X(\eta)<1$. Drawing the graph of $G_X$ should make this clear...

Comment: Condition on extinction: imagine some generation has size $n$. Their offspring have size $k_1$, ..., $k_n$, with probability $p_{k_1}\cdots p_{k_n}$. These all die with probability $\eta^{k_1+\cdots +k_n}$, thus the offspring of the  conditioned process  have size $k_1$, ..., $k_n$, with probability proportional to $\eta^{k_1+\cdots +k_n}p_{k_1}\cdots p_{k_n}=\prod\limits_i(\eta^{k_i}p_{k_i})\propto p'_{k_1}\cdots p'_{k_n}$, qed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did not see that and thought that you would mention that $G_X'(\eta) < 1$ for something different. So what you're aiming at is that since $G_{X'}$ is increasing and strictly convex it has 2 fixed points, which is only possible if the derivative at $\eta$ (the first fixed point) is $<1$? The conclusion is that this process is subcritical, and hence must get extinct with probability 1. Thanks a lot. This makes sense to me.

Comment: Concerning your last comment: Do I misunderstand or miss something or why do you have $\eta^{k}$ whereas $p_k':=\eta^{k-1} p_k$, so where is the factor $\eta$ going? So you use the "proportional" sign in the last step - this is exactly this issue? And also why would a "proportional" sign there be what we want, why not an equality? Sorry if these questions are stupid, but I don't get it.

Comment: Not an equality because of the probabilities in the various denominators involved when conditioning.